# How to get the user usage total average time in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

I want know how to get the total users website usage total average time for **each day**. I'm saving the details in database user coming time closing time with **FORMAT - DATETIME**

```
SELECT `acu_name` ,AVG(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(acu_et) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(acu_at)) AS totalTime
ROM `active_user`
GROUP BY `acu_name`
```

Result :- user01 - 1396.6667
          user02 - 2455.0000

here it's coming each user usage time with UNIX_TIMESTAMP FORMAT i want to get that like example(30min or 1hour 30min) and same time i want to get the total users usage time also **using laravel** and i attached the table format with details please help me to find how out how to do this functions.[image]

Comment: use `datediff` function for more https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017 . If you want human related time than use `diffForHumans()`

Comment: i tried but error is showing

Comment: SELECT `acu_name` , DATEDIFF(day, `acu_at`, `acu_et`) AS totalTime               FROM `active_user`               GROUP BY `acu_name`;

Error is : Error Code: 1582. Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'DATEDIFF' 0.250 sec

Comment: `DATEDIFF(day, acu_at, acu_et)` should not, afaik, have the `day` so should be `DATEDIFF( acu_at, acu_et )`?

Comment: `SELECT acu_name , DATEDIFF( acu_at, acu_et) AS totalTime FROM active_user GROUP BY acu_name` try with this

Comment: Still struggling? See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: the result is coming null